# Несколько условий в операторе IF

Tags: delphi

```
begin
    if edit1.Text='' or Edit2.text='' then
       label1.Caption:='0';
end;
```

Как я помню, несколько условий вводить через and или or, но не работает. Наверно я нуб.

Comment: Все нормально, я тоже как-то на этом месте запнулся. @Dex все правильно написал.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

отдельные условия возьмите в скобки:

```
begin
    if (edit1.Text='') or (Edit2.text='') then
        label1.Caption:='0';
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

- `and` - когда нужно чтобы обе части условия выполнялись.
- `or` - одна из них.

`label1.Caption:=0;`  - тут ошибка. `Caption` - строковое свойство и  ему нельзя присвоить число.

Answer (score -1):

```
"begin
    if (edit1.Text='') or (Edit2.text='') then
        label1.Caption:=' ';
 end;
 ---
 begin
    Label1.Caption := IntToStr(0);
 end;"
```

0 как цифру можно 'присвоить' -
"Label1.Caption := IntToStr(0);"

Comment: Непонятно чем ваш ответ принципиально отличается от данного 13 лет назад..

Comment: А  вы к чему ответили что 0 нельзя присвоить Label1.Caption? Что-то изменилось на сегодняшний день (2024 год) в вашем представлении? Зачем ввели в заблуждение человека?  Потренируйтесь с приведённым примером. Возможно ваше убеждённость изменится.